# Plotly deactivate x axis sorting

Tags: python, plotly

I want to plot a bar chart. On the x-axis are IDs of consultants. They range between 1000 and 2000. Each consultant has a specific number of customers (y-axis).

Now I want to plot a bar chart in plotly. But plotly orders the consultant IDs ascending and interprets them as integer, but they are not. They shall be ordered like the list I give plotly.

By the way in matplotlib the order is right.

```
trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=consultants, 
    y=info[0,:]
)
trace2 = go.Bar(
    x=consultants,
    y=info[1,:],
)
trace3 = go.Bar(
    x=consultants,
    y=info[2,:]
)
trace4 = go.Bar(
   x=consultants,
   y=info[3,:]
)

data = [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4]
layout = go.Layout(
       barmode='stack',
       xaxis=dict(
       categoryorder='array',
       categoryarray=consultants,
       titlefont=dict(
         size=18,
         color='black'),
       showticklabels=True,
       tickfont=dict(
        size=16,
        color='black',
        ),
    tickangle=20
    ),
yaxis=dict(
    title='Number of customers',
       titlefont=dict(
        size=18,
        color='black'),
    showgrid=True,
    showline=False,
    showticklabels=True,
    tickfont=dict(
        size=16,
        color='black')
    ),

  )

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='stacked-bar')
```

Comment: Have a look at: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-categoryorder

Comment: Seems to be the rigth keyword. But if I type categoryorder='array'. How should the categoryarray look like? Is it list(range(len(num_consultants))) or num_consultants. Till now there is now effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly Plotly seems to ignore `categoryorder` for integers but disabling of sorting can be achieved by passing [`type='category`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-type) in `xaxis` in `layout`.

> `type ( enumerated : "-" | "linear" | "log" | "date" | "category" )`
>
> default: "-"
>   Sets the axis type. By default, plotly attempts to
>   determined the axis type by looking into the data of the traces that
>   referenced the axis in question.

[image]

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

consultants = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]
info = np.random.randint(100, size=(5,5))

data = []
for i in range(len(info)):
    data.append(go.Bar(x=consultants, 
                       y=info[i,:]))

layout = go.Layout(barmode='stack', 
                   xaxis=dict(type='category'),
                   yaxis=dict(title='Number of customers'))

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename='stacked-bar')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Prints in `0 1 2 3 4` I want `4 3 2 1 0`
Here is the code

```python

    xaxis=dict(type='category',
              tickvals = ["4", "3", "2" ,"1", "0"]
              )
    )
     ```

Answer (score 5):

The lastest version of Plotly now has a variable in the layout options to specify a categorical layout for the X axis:

```
fig.update_layout(
xaxis_type = 'category'
)
```