# Plotly graph - yAxis unordered on aggregation of categorical fields

Tags: javascript, angular, graph, plotly, plotly.js

[Categorical Y axis Field aggregated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydMGc.png)

In this graph, the count aggregation is applied and the yAxis is not ordered.

the yAxis has categorical values (could be seen before aggregation)

this issue is not existant while having the numerical values in the yAxis.

For testing:

https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/veoNdB
In the above code pen, use this code

```
    var score = ['Moe','Larry','Curly','Moe','Larry','Curly','Moe','Larry','Curly','Moe','Larry','Curly']
var subject = [1,6,2,8,2,9,4,5,1,5,2,8]
```

instead of

```
var subject = ['Moe','Larry','Curly','Moe','Larry','Curly','Moe','Larry','Curly','Moe','Larry','Curly']
var score = [1,6,2,8,2,9,4,5,1,5,2,8]
```

The above example may look a bit odd but its just for testing

Answer (score 0):

From having found the following subject on stackoverflow: [Plotly deactivate x axis sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47489554/plotly-deactivate-x-axis-sorting), I think the mistakes may arise in your layout type on y axis. Is it set on 'category' ? If so, it is not getting the sort function of Plotly.

Here is the same example shown by Plotly with unordered numbers:

https://codepen.io/Aymer-El/pen/QWNBbge

```
yaxis: {title: 'Score', range: [0,22], type:"category"}

layout = {  title: '<b>Plotly Aggregations</b><br>use dropdown to change aggregation',  xaxis: {title: 'Subject'},  yaxis: {title: 'Score', range: [0,22], type:"category"},  height: 600,  width: 900,...}
```

Comment: yes. in this code pen, the yAxis has got numerical values. which means, after count aggregation, the count values are ordered

Comment: type ( enumerated : "-" | "linear" | "log" | "date" | "category" ), there is no numerical types. 
Do you have the layout structure in your code ?